# Getting links from table via HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have simple html table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="http://someurl_1.com">item name1</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      Value 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="http://someurl_2.com">item name2</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      Value 2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now I need to have data from that table as List>(or string[][])

to get it I use:

```
        List<List<string>>
            table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table")
                    .Descendants("tr")
                    .Skip(1)
                    .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() > 1)
                    .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
                    .ToList();
```

it, succesfully gets me only string data, so in result I have

```
table[0][0] -> item name1
table[0][1] -> value 1
table[1][0] -> item name2
table[1][1] -> value 2
```

but I don't have url's in that array.

How can I get it to the table value, so in result I need to have like:

```
table[0][0] -> http://someurl_1.com
table[0][1] -> item name1
table[0][2] -> value 1
table[1][0]-> http://someurl_2.com
table[1][1] -> item name2
table[1][2] -> value 2
```

Any help appreciate! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the xpath for each cell and mapping their data to your array.

For example the xpath of the second item is **/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a**

```cs
  var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
  doc.LoadHtml(htmlText);
  var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a");
```

will give you `<a href="http://someurl_2.com">item name2</a>` as a node which you can prase futher to grab url or text.